# How to prevent negative number input on keydown in ASP.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using asp.net textbox with textmode=numeric. The issue is, if I am having 0 in textbox, on keydown it shows -ve value. I don't want to show negative value in textbox on any keypress.

Is anybody having idea how to stop keydown on 0 and avoid negative value input.

Comment: any code? to show
However you can check the input on keydown event perform your operation accordingly

Answer (score 4):

use min attribute like :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="Number" min="0"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: same 'min' attribute as in regular <input type='number'> element :-)